Can in-app purchases via StoreKit work on macOS in a Developer-ID signed app?
This seems like an obvious question, but I can't find documentation on it anywhere. If I have an app in the Mac App Store with in-app purchase functionality, and I build and sign it using my Developer-ID certificate and notarize it, is there a way for in-app purchases to work in that build of the app?
So far when I export and sign as Developer-ID, purchases work but they're in the sandbox environment. I'd like them to use the Production environment.

Per Supported capabilities (macOS) on the Apple Developer website it shows only apps signed/provisioned for the App Store can use In-App Purchase, refer to the matrix.
